# Blender Coordinate Conversion causes Flipped Rotation

Tags: python, matrix, coordinates, blender

In Blender I am importing location/rotation data in the form of a list of floats. The raw data is in an X forward coordinate system, and I want to rotate it 90 degrees around the world origin to match Blenders coordinate system. This adjusted rotation however is causing certain objects to ‘flip’ around randomly.

```
raw_data = [1.24477, -2.01742, -0.001801461, 2.5548, -0.137604, 0.403129, -0.904739]
raw_location = raw_data[:3]
raw_rotation = raw_data[3:]
loc = Vector(raw_location)
rot = Quaternion((raw_rotation[4], raw_rotation[5], raw_rotation[6]), raw_rotation[3])
raw_matrix = Matrix.LocRotScale(loc, rot.normalized(), None)
m = Matrix.Rotation(radians(deg), 4, 'Z') @ raw_matrix
```

[Rotation "Flipping"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlFK5.jpg)

I’m still new to linear algebra, but I would expect something like this to happen at 180 degrees, however as you can see in the screenshot this object goes to a maximum of 177 degrees.

On a side note, after I fix the rotations manually by adjusting the keys in the graph editor, if I get the objects world matrix and run the “to_euler()” function it will report the wrong values.

[to_euler() not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGsEs.jpg)

I am using Blender 3.3.3 LTS. I have a Blender file illustrating the issue if that helps as well. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you post a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's hard to see what's going on without the exact code. For one seeing how you set an object's rotation with bpy might gives clues as to what is happening.